# Add Dynamic Month in Responsive Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a responsive calendar for my website, the script i'm using is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '2015-12',
      events: {
        "2015-12-18": {},
        "2015-12-21": {},
        "2015-12-23": {}
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm trying to put dynamic months through PHP in it and doing following changes in the script

```
time: '<?php echo('Y-m'); ?>',
```

but it is not returning anything

Comment: You want to echo the result of `date('Y-m')`, not just echo `Y-m`.

Comment: I'm not sure if JS will detect `'<?php echo('Y-m'); ?>',` as snippet.

Comment: @JonStirling: thanks it's work for me, I was missing date function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing with this :

```
time: '<?php echo date("Y-m"); ?>'
```

Comment: Always here to help :)